# python dict values in elif loop

Tags: python

each time i type a value  the code gives me "subscribe" ...how to get the dict value?

```
Friends = {
    'rolf' : 'blue',
    'ronnie' : 'green',
    'barbara' : 'purple',
    'benny' : 'kaki',
    'stewart' : 'yellow',
    'mickey' : 'red'
}


def greetagain():

    friend = input("Enter your friend name or color? ")
    i = Friends.values()

    if friend in Friends.keys():
        print('yes it matches')
    elif i in Friends.values():
        print('ok ok')
    else:
        print('subscribe')

greetagain()
```

Comment: `i`  should just be `friend` in your elif statement.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.
Please note the change below, you use the variable friend without the `i`,
since you can check with friend values and keys

```
def greetagain():

    friend = input("Enter your friend name or color? ")

    if friend in Friends.keys():
        print('yes it matches')
    elif friend in Friends.values():
        print('ok ok')
    else:
        print('subscribe')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer   it helps

Answer (score 0):

i could only understand a part of your question, so, i have tried my best to explain it.

The if condition already works as it is. I think you want to retrieve the name of the friend (key) in the elif condition, for that you can try the following code:

```
Friends = { 'rolf' : 'blue', 'ronnie' : 'green', 'barbara' : 'purple', 'benny' : 'kaki', 'stewart' : 'yellow', 'mickey' : 'red' }

def greetagain():
    friend = input("Enter your friend name or color? ")

    if friend in Friends.keys():
        print('Key matches')
        print("Color associted to friend is:", Friends[friend])
    elif friend in Friends.values():
        for key, value in Friends.items(): 
            if friend == value: 
                print('Color is present in list and associated by:', key)
    else:
        print('subscribe')

greetagain()
```

Comment: Thank you  i was trying to display the value